# Wordpress WooCommerce add to cart not working on mobile site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing an eCommerce website using wordpress and [cilo wordpress theme](http://demo.thimpress.com/?theme=cilo).

The site is coming all together on desktop and other media but when my screen size is less than 769px, add to cart button is not working for signle product page. [Click here](http://shophouseofluxe.com/product/sun-king-table-lamp/) to see an example post

- The theme is working perfectly on the demo
- This theme use woocommerce inside theme folder
- tried other themes on my site, where add to cart is working on mobile
  site
- I tried to upgrade everything including the latest version of the theme and the wordpress itself

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sidebar widget seems to be the problem as this is going full width and causing an overlay over the content although the text is now hidden.

If you use chrome and go into developer mode you can see the elements causing the overlay.

My recommendation would be amending your responsive css to put a `display: none;` on this element like so:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #secondary {
        display:none
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Stewartside,

That's a great and quick solution. Thanks much for your help.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to vote you up. I am new user and hope I would have the reputation soon to vote.

Comment: I am having another issue, with the product have multiple images, the images and content getting cut off when the screen site is less than 405px wide, like in my iPhone 4s. 

But with the product have single image has not issue with that. [Here is a link] (http://shophouseofluxe.com/product/scanner-out-of/) and here is a screenshot http://www.imageno.com/un63onojlk6hpic.html        @Stewartside